# How to get DegreesLatitude value from *proto.LiveLocationMessage on whatsmeow golang package

Tags: go, whatsapp

I'm new on golang. I just have python basic, so I just don't know what is *proto variable. I just try https://go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/ package. run it and try to get livelocation from the sender. But the value is weird, it says *proto.LiveLocationMessage type. this is my log :

```
16:35:23.328 [Client/Recv DEBUG] <message from="6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net" id="89A2DDE29A7F0ED72ACB6E5C7BE4030F" notify="Rolly Maulana Awangga" t="1663839323" type="media"><enc duration="3600" mediatype="livelocation" type="pkmsg" v="2"><!-- 4247 bytes --></enc></message>
16:35:23.328 [Client DEBUG] Decrypting 1 messages from 6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net
16:35:23.328 [Client/Send DEBUG] <ack class="message" id="89A2DDE29A7F0ED72ACB6E5C7BE4030F" to="6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net"/>
GetConversation :  
Sender :  6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net
Sender Number :  6281312000300
IsGroup :  false
MessageSource :  {6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net 6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net false false }
ID :  89A2DDE29A7F0ED72ACB6E5C7BE4030F
PushName :  Rolly Maulana Awangga
BroadcastListOwner :
Category :
Chat :  6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net
DeviceSentMeta :  <nil>
IsFromMe :  false
MediaType :  livelocation
Multicast :  false
Info.Chat.Server :  s.whatsapp.net
liveloc *proto.LiveLocationMessage
Latitude :  0xc00010d3e8
Longitude :  0xc00010d3f0
livelocation :  degreesLatitude:-6.8732719  degreesLongitude:107.5753975  sequenceNumber:1663839322967001  jpegThumbnail:"\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xe2\x02(ICC_PROFILE\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x02\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x10\x00\x00mntrRGB XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00acsp\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\xf6\xd6\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd3-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\tdesc\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00trXYZ\x00\x00\x01d\x00\x00\x00\x14gXYZ\x00\x00\x01x\x00\x00\x00\x14bXYZ\x00\x00\x01\x8c\x00\x00\x00\x14rTRC\x00\x00\x01\xa0\x00\x00\x00(gTRC\x00\x00\x01\xa0\x00\x00\x00(bTRC\x00\x00\x01\xa0\x00\x00\x00(wtpt\x00\x00\x01\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x14cprt\x00\x00\x01\xdc\x00\x00\x00<mluc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0cenUS\x00\x00\x00X\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00s\x00R\x00G\x00B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00o\xa2\x00\x008\xf5\x00\x00\x03\x90XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b\x99\x00\x00\xb7\x85\x00\x00\x18\xdaXYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$\xa0\x00\x00\x0f\x84\x00\x00\xb6\xcfpara\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02ff\x00\x00\xf2\xa7\x00\x00\rY\x00\x00\x13\xd0\x00\x00\n[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf6\xd6\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd3-mluc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0cenUS\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00G\x00o\x00o\x00g\x00l\x00e\x00 \x00I\x00n\x00c\x00.\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x006\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x06\x04\x05\x06\x05\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06\x07\x07\x06\x08\n\x10\n\n\t\t\n\x14\x0e\x0f\x0c\x10\x17\x14\x18\x18\x17\x14\x16\x16\x1a\x1d%\x1f\x1a\x1b#\x1c\x16\x16 , #&')*)\x19\x1f-0-(0%()(\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x07\x07\x07\n\x08\n\x13\n\n\x13(\x1a\x16\x1a((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x00d\x00d\x03\x01\"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\x03\x04\x07\x05\x06\x08\xff\xc4\x00=\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x02\x03\x06\x03\x03\x0b\x03\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05!\x121A\x06\x13\"Qaq\x14\x81\xd1\x07\x91\xf0\x15#23BR\xa1\xb1\xc1\xe1\xf1$b\x82\x16&S\x92\x93\xff\xc4\x00\x1b\x01\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x05\x04\x06\x07\xff\xc4\x00'\x11\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x03\x03\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x12\x04!1\x05A\xf0\x06\"qQa\xb1\xd1\xf1\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xd1\xfbt\xf3j}\xa7\xb5\xd2\x04\xf1\xdbĪ\x1b3\xbf\n\x07`w'\xd8\x00=ϝw\xe0\xfb1\xb1\xfc\x9eR[\xd9\xda\xed\xb7\x12\xa0\x01\x07\xfcz\x8f\x9f\xdd\\\x0f\xb4\xcd\"E\xb8\x8fU\x85s\x0f\n\xc3.\x07蜞\x13\xecs\x8f\xbbΡ\xd3\xfbS\xa7[\xe9\x10\xdbI\x06\xa5đ\x84{t\xb9\xc4\x12\xb0\x18\xc9\xfd\xa1\x9ed\r\xbd\rm\xbbK\x13ϲ\x93\xc8}\x1a\xda\xe3\xb2ݸ\x87O{\x88\xa7[\x80\x11\xfb\xa6\xc8 \x82W#\xa1\xe4}\x8f\xadj\x91\x8e\x1b?Yd\xfe\x03\xfc\x7f\x1a\xca\xfb\x19h\xfa\xcfhcԚ#\x1d\xb5\x94QG\xb9\xc8i\x16%A\xbf\xb0\xe2\xf4ڵQ\xb46\xa3\xfd\xa4\xfe>\xfa\xac\xf9/O\x82\xa5\xfd\xc7\xc3A<\xe7\x9axW>x\xcd\x14\x0b*\xdbDn[\x89\xf0\ta\xcdOҊu\\H\xae\x01]\xdb\x07\x91\x18\xc1\x1f\x8f:\xab\r\xcai\xa5\xa0\xbd\x99c\x80\x0e(e\x91\xb08z\xa9'\xa8\xfeU)'\x17n|\xf3\xf8[|\x8b\xcdq\x15\xbcO-ۤPƼO#\x1c.<\xeb\xc4\xde\xea\x1a\xb5\xc5\xf5\x8dͽʨi\x8b@\xbe\x17\
x8ePAR\xb0˲\x9f>\t\x02\xb6Fƻ\xb3\xdd\xe9\x1a\xecKec\xabۼ\xa2U\x95~\x16t\x91\x91\xd7pJ\xee\x08\xce64\x1d\x9a\xd1f\xd3\xef溜Z\xf1\x18\x99;\xe82\r\xd33\xf1\x99$SȌm\xcf\xf4\x8fL\n\xcd4\xf7E\xe5\x17\x17f\xacva\x87\xe0\xed\xfb\xbe>\xf6vb\xcf!P\xa6G<\xc9\x03a\xc8}\xd4Q.XuT\xeb\xe6\xddM31f\xe2^g\u009f\xd4ѷ\x81\x15\x13\xf4\x8e\xc3\xebB\x03V\xc1iq\x9e\x13\u0083Ϳ\xb7֢h\xdb\x1b\x93 \xe6CsϘ4\x8b\x16\x8dT)1\xa1\u0090|Y\xf3\xa7Y\x08\x19>5\xfd\xe5\x1f\xccP\x02$#a*\x0fG\x1b\x8aTL\xcc\xc7\"\x1c\x8f6\xc0\xa5@T\x9e(線\x19\x91^'!YXd\x
10F\xe2\xb2\x1dO\xb3\xb2\xdb\xf6\xa54\x88\t\"v\x06\x17;\xe23\x93\x93\xed\x86\xf7\xc5kvז\x97I\x1f\xc3]\xc1/\x7f\x18\x9e \xae2\xc8\x0e\x0b\x00zSKam%\xfc7\xaf\x12\xb5\xd4HV93\xc9[\x9e:U\xa3,JJ*@\xe9\xb6\x11i\xd66\xf6\xd6q\xf0\xc0\x10c'\xaf2I\xf35ڷ\x8cKf\x88\xe7ļ\x8a\x9e^Uφ\xfa8\xa7[U\x9d>!m\xc4\xc6\x1f\xda(O\x08>\xd9\x18\xab\x16šV(\xb1\xa9`\x08\xe6z\x8f\xadU\x97C]\xba\xdaB\xf2^ab\x8c\x172\x11\xe1\xc0\x19ϥ|\xef\xda\xfe\xd2\xdd\xeb\xfa\x8b\xcfr\xec\x96\xf1\xb10\xc2N\xd1\x0f\xaf\x99\xfe\x98\x03x\xed%\xe5\xb5։\xabi\xb3]\xdb%İ\x9b\\\x07\xddd\x95H\x8c\x11\xd39ھg\xbe\x85\xa4Ib9G;a\x86\x089\xe4k\x9b\xd4'$\xa3\x15\xc3>\xab\xd3\x14iNU*5y.\x05\x05\xdaH\xff\x00\x99\x97,\xa7\x8b\xd8\xf9֫\xd9\x1f\xb4
d\x87Ik=ang\xba\x88~nH\xc0%\x93\x96䑸\xf3\xeb\x91\xcc\xe4\xd65ag,W\x1d\xe4\x98P3\xd79\xad/쯲\x91v\x8bT\xb9\x9e\xf1\xe4[Kh°C\x82\xcc\xc4\x103\xec\xa7>\xe3μ\xfa)8\xd6QOfuz\xf5\x18\xd5\xd0ʤդ\xb84\xdd\x0b\xb5\xbaV\xads\xdc\xc0\xf2E9\x18\x8e\x19S\x0c@\x1b\xe3\x19\x07\xe4zW{\xc4\xcd\xe4\xec?\xf5_\xadf\x1d\xb3\xecg\xfd=\x0f\xe5\x0b+\xf0`WP\xab!\xe1\x95X\x9d\xb8H\xe6v'\xa7/Jл9w6\xa1\xd9\xfb+\xc3\x13\x17\x9a \xccA\x07-\x8c\x1f\xe2+\xb9$\xb9G\xe7\xb1n\xf6\x91\xd0v\x11\xa8U\xc7Ҁeۊ<\x07\xc6\x08=}hgA\x1c\xc5A'\x00g'\xad(\x81.1U.K\xdc'\xed\x0e#\xe6w\xa5RR\xa02\xed%\xa5\x9b\xb3Vv\x82y\"\x84\xf6nyOw\x80x\x96U\xeb\x8eDd\x1fBjŽ\xee\xa3\x06\x9d\xd9]*\xc2[\xf6\x8a},\\\x97\xb7\x92\x15\x91\xdb\x0b\xe0\r&\x00U\xcf!\xbe1\xe4k\xd9\xe9\xa6\xc2M6\xce\xf2\xd6\xde\xda\x08\xa7\xb4Qn\xad\nFDn\x03w~X\xe5\x95\x1bf\x82}+I[\x18\xecnl4\xe5\xb4B\xcf\x1c\x12\"\x05S̐\x0f/\\U\xeef\xa2gڎ\xaf\x
ac\xdb\xea\xf6\x973b+\x994h\x92\xf6\xee\x0e\t>\x1e?\x89pҀ\xa4\x868\xc1\xd8\xed\x92zWoZ\xbc\xd4>'\xb5RYk7\x91\xc1\xa5Z[Ol\xa8\xca\xca\xe4\xc6\xc7,H$\x83\x8f\x9ek\xd8|5\xacl\x9f鬐\xc9\x17\xc3'\x81\x07\x14|\xfb\xb1\xe6\xbb\xf2\xe5C<Z]\x9d\x9dꭕ\x89\x02\x0e\x19m\xa2H\xc1\x95Q\t\x08A\xc08\x1c\x81\xd8\x03L\x86/\xeax^\xd4jWS\xa5\xf4\xa1;\xe6\x8e\xefK\x96(\x01\x0b\x96e\xe2*\x0f\xa9\xaf\x15\xda\xed.g\xb5]uۊk\x9b\x89#\xbd\x87\x83\x83\xe1n2ILyc\x91\xeb\x82O\xe9\n\xdd\x1a\xd2\xceX\x16O\x80\xb6\r(\x8d\xf8^\x14'\x89G\x838\xc8\xca\xf2\x1e]+\x99\xda\xdd*\xdbRit\xf5\x86\x18\x9a\xf1\x0bM*\xa0\x0cΫ\xe0f8ܩ+\x8c\xd65\xa8\xaa\xf0p\xf3d{\xfav\xb2z\x1dDk'\xb7\x0f\xe1\xb3\xe7\x9b[i\xae\xee#\xb7\xb5\x8c\xc9<\x8c\x15\x10u'`+\xd9\xf6.\xfa߳\xadq\x1d\xecw\xa9;c2ۿ\x04\x91\xb8' \xa9؏C\x9eB\xad}\x8f\xe9\xa9q\xac]_J\x84\x1bX׻\rџ#>\xe0+\x0f\xf9Ww\xed+DA\x10\xd5\xed\xd7\x0c\x08K\x80:\x83\x
b2\xb7\xbep>cʼ\xbd6\x8a\x8cr\x97,\xebz\x9f]*\xd5U\x18?lw\xf9o\xf4p\xf5}Muۖ\xb1\xd2\xedg/s$</<\xa5\xdd\xd9\x04\x99-\xff\x00Ӧ\xc0-jz\x16\x9e\x96\x16\xd6Vp\x93\x88QT\xb0؜\r\xc9
\xf7\xfe\xb5\xe6~\xce4H-4\xc5\xd4nK\xad\xdd\xd2\xe5<\x19\t\x1fL{\xf3?/*\xf6\xa8\xab\x1c\x13H\x92\xf1\x92;\xb1\xe1+\x8c\xfb\xd7Bo\xb2>j\x9c{\xb2\x17~\xf2G\x93\xf7\x8eG\xb7O\xe1S@\xb8\x05\xbc\xea\x00:\n\xb6\xa3\n\x05P\xd0zU\x1bw\xccǹ@\xca6$\x9e\xb4\xa8\x0c\xba\xff\x00I\xbd1\xe9cQ\x82Aj\xda,\x16\xd1\xf1i\xafvb\x90/\x8d8C\x03\x1b\xe7\x1e\"=21G\xaf\xd9-\x9d\xae\xb5\xf9v\xc6\xea\xfaW\xd2aK\x1b\xa7\xb5.c)\t\x0eI\x19\x11\xb7\x1f\x88\xef\xf35\xeb\xef\xfbQ\xa6X]\xdd\xc14\xd7D\xda\xf7}\xfc\xb1[\xbb\xc7\x18u\x0c\xacXl\x06\x08\xae'\xda\x06\xa5\xa5\xda[j\x8e\x96\xdf\x17\xaa\xc1\x0ci#\x18\x1eH\x14\x16\x05V_\xd8'\x04\x91\xc5Z&̚I\\\xe5kZ]\xd5\xcd\xf4\xedx\x92\x1b{\x9b\x0bh\xec\xe5M5\xae\xd9p\x9b\xaa2
\xb0\xeeۋ-\xbf=\xb7ں͡I\xff\x00z\xdcOc$\xd7\xf2[\x98\xad\xa7xO\x1c\x99\xb5\xe1<\x1ed\x9c\x83\x8fj\xf4ך\xfe\x9ff\x9a\xbdĲ\xca#\xd3\x19R\xe0,|\x8b\x01\x8cy\xf3\x15\r\xdfj\xb4\x
b8n絑\xae\xb3\x04\xe2\xdaY~\x1d\xccQ\xb9\xc7\x0f\x13\x8d\x80$\x81QvN)w:\xbaJ\x11id\x92)N\xe6\x042\x06\x18\xe1!\x06\xc7\xf1Ҩ\xb3\xf7\xfa\xc3H\xbb\xaaFA>LǗ\xdc\x05UֻQ\xa7ڙ\xac
\x16k\xae8]a\x9a\xe1-\x9aH\xd6F \x05-\xcb>!\xb6~\x95\xd1HR\xd6>\xee0xW9'\x9b\x1e\xa4\xfa\xd4\xc5\xe2\x9b\xee\xc9{\xbb\x154\xad\"\xc7J\xef\xff\x00'ۈ{\xf7\xe3\x93\x0cNO\xcc\xec=\x06¬^\xda\xc1}i-\xb5\xd4bH%^\x17C\xd4U\x89\x11\xe2\xc7x\xbc9\xe4r\x0ehI\x00d\x9d\xab4\xad\xc1\xa4\xa4\xe4\xef'v\x0cQ\xa41$q\xa8X\xd1B\xaa\x8e@\x0eB\xa5;Z/\xfb\xe5'\xe4\x06(\x92\x12W\x8eS\xddG\xe6y\x9faDB\xc8c\x08\xa5b@q\x9em\x9ef\x84\x01\x08\xcb\xfboV(Q\x02\xe7\x1dh\x89\xc0\xc9\xe5@G\xf1\r\x01(\xac\xb8';\xa9<\xfd\xa9T\xd0\xcd\x14\x11/z\xc1]\xfcx>\xbc\xa9P\x1e6~\xca^ɧv\x96\x01=\xa7\x1e\xa7\x05\xb4P\x9e&\u0098\xe2Tn/\x0e\xc3#lf\xaa뽙\xd5d\xb4\xd74\xfb\t4\xe3i\xaa\x94\x94\xcb<\xae\xaf\x13\xa8P\xc3\x01NA\xe1\x18;cz\xf7;7\x11bDh<Ds'\xa0\x14\x94\xb2\xfe\xa9R,\xf3#\xc4\xc7\xe6\x7f\xbdNL\xae(\xf1\x1d\xa4\xd05;\xc6\xed\x15\xb6\x9f.\x9cmu\x86\x8aN\xf2y\x99^\"\x81A^\x10\xa79\xe1\xd8՝c\xb3\x972i\xbd\xa1\xb2\x13ڋ\x8dZ\xfa;\x98\x01f\xc0Eh\xc9\r\xe1\xd8\xf8\x0f,׮yd\x8d\x19\xcc\xed£'\x88\x0cc\x9a+\xb8⹖&\x86F@C\x8d\xf0\x0f\x9dY7\xc9\x0e(\xce5\xf6\x9a\xd2\xebTЬ崹7\xfa\xa4w=\xde\\\\)gG /\x0e\n\x8e\x1c\xf1\xe7\x00z֔\xf6һ\xbb)\x8c\xa1$\xe7\x8b\xfbT\xbf\x9dU\x05H\x96?\xdeO\xa7ҢN\x12Ţb\xadׇo\xbc}j\xadܲV\x05$X\xd6\x08\"1\xc8\x0bx\xce27?拼\x8d
D\xd2$\x11\x86\x8d\xf8T\xf4\xe7\x8c━d\xfd|{\xff\x00\xe4\x8fc\xf3\x1f\xe6\x98\xc4\x12\xdd\x15\\:\xbc\xb9\xc8\x18\xd8\x0f\xedPHȦF\xef%%\x9b\xa6jRp2yP`\xf0#\x02G\x13a\x00\xe5\xc29\x9fǥ\x1d\x00\xc8\x1aWU\x01\xd0\x1d\xcbp\xf4\xf4\xa0+ޫ$R\xab\x93\xb1G\xf0\xb5\x12\xb3,\x1c*\xcc8\xdf\x0b\xbf%\x1c\xff\x00\x1e\xb4\x9f.1*$\xc3\xfd\xdb0\xf9\x8a\x02Y\xac\xc
5\xc3\xf7\x8cJ\x12?D\x80qJ\x99&\x91\x14*D\xa1G.)\t?ʕ\x00&)D1\xe5Tx\x99\x983`\r\xf6\xa0\xca\xf5\x9c\x1fH\x97\x8b\xf8\xf2\xa7h\x88\x8b\x05\t\x11ɷ\x84\x9d\x88\xfa\xd2\xe3\xe7\u00927\xb2\x1a\x00;\xb1<\x9d\xde\x1c\xc4G\xe7;\xc27\x1f* \xa6\x05\xe1t*\x83`y\x8ct\xfc\x1ap\x92\x1bX\xbc\x04\xa3\x0e7Q\xcf'\x96|\xe9\xa38\xfdK\x95\xc75\x1c\xbe\xea\x01\xd4\x0c\xf1\xc6\xc5I꧟։\x9f\x8b\x1d\xfca\xf1\xc9\xd3f\x14'\x879x\xf8O\xefŷ\xde?\xcd:\x86 \x98\xd9e\x03\x98\x1e\x16\x1f#@?\x032\x93o\"\xc9\xe8\xdb0\xf7\xa0\x91s:@\xb9\x1c*\x14\x1f\xe2[\xf1֞ \x11L\xee\x1f\xbdRT+\x0c\x02O\x97\\Q%ã\x04\x94\x89\x14\x82I\xc6\x08\x14\x00\x96Vf\x90m\x1a\x8e\x15\xf4Q\xf8\xfeU\x06_\x89pO\x1bt\xcf,\xec\x06?\x1c\xaat\x8a)\x80X\xa
4e\x1b\x13\x1b\x8e\x94\x95\x1a\x16\x92Y\x97\x1c\x1b\x8d\xf6bv\x1f\x8fZ\x01\xd8\x01/\n\xfe\x8c`\"\xff\x00_ǥ>Fq\x9d\xe8[\xbb`\xdd\xe4\\\x0eH=\xe2\x0c\xef\x9c\xd2h\xf1\x1a2b_\x11ft\x1e\x98\x03\x14\x043d\xc8s)\x8f\x1b\x01\x8e~\xb4\xaauea\x95 \x8aT\x07;@U\xb2\xb0\xd5\x16\xd9U#\x8e\xf2^\xee00\xa86\xd8\x01\xc8s8\xf5\xa2\xbe\x9easb\x82i\x02\xcc\xe4>\x0e6\xc7*T\xabJJ\xf2\xdf\xef\xf8+7d_\x90q\\\xcarAR\x14\x10q\x81\x81\xf5\xa5l~&I\x12`\tM\x83\x8d\x9b\xef\x14\xa9Ve\x80\xc9[\x97\x8b9U\x19\x04\xf3\xa7\x95AR\xc4n\x06Ǩ\xa5J\x807$\x98\x15\x898\x8f\x8b~\xa7ΫJ\x7f\xd4\x14\xe8\xd8\x07ڕ*\x02c\xfa\xa9ϛ*|\xb6\xfa\x9aq;\xc5\x15\xba\x8c0ve<[\xed\x9aT\xa8\n}\xa9g\xb1\xd1\xde[7hdy\xa1\x87\x89\x7fd<\xa8\xa4\x8e\x80\xe1\x8d.\xce\xddK{\x02\xdcNA\x90\xcdr\xbe\x11\x8d\x92R\xaa6\xe7\x80)R\xa7`\\\xb5u\xb9\x8b\xbc\x9a\x18\x99\xf3\x8c\xf0ҥJ\x80\xff\xd9"
16:35:23.383 [Client/Send DEBUG] <receipt id="89A2DDE29A7F0ED72ACB6E5C7BE4030F" to="6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net" type="inactive"/>
```

if I use v.Message.LiveLocationMessage variable the latitude shows correctly. but if I use v.Message.LiveLocationMessage.DegreesLatitude show weird number 0xc00010d3e8. this is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"

    "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow"
    "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/store/sqlstore"
    "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/types/events"
    waLog "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/util/log"
)

var client *whatsmeow.Client

func eventHandler(evt interface{}) {
    switch v := evt.(type) {
    case *events.Message:
        if !v.Info.IsFromMe {
            fmt.Println("GetConversation : ", v.Message.GetConversation())
            fmt.Println("Sender : ", v.Info.Sender)
            fmt.Println("Sender Number : ", v.Info.Sender.User)
            fmt.Println("IsGroup : ", v.Info.IsGroup)
            fmt.Println("MessageSource : ", v.Info.MessageSource)
            fmt.Println("ID : ", v.Info.ID)
            fmt.Println("PushName : ", v.Info.PushName)
            fmt.Println("BroadcastListOwner : ", v.Info.BroadcastListOwner)
            fmt.Println("Category : ", v.Info.Category)
            fmt.Println("Chat : ", v.Info.Chat)
            fmt.Println("DeviceSentMeta : ", v.Info.DeviceSentMeta)
            fmt.Println("IsFromMe : ", v.Info.IsFromMe)
            fmt.Println("MediaType : ", v.Info.MediaType)
            fmt.Println("Multicast : ", v.Info.Multicast)
            fmt.Println("Info.Chat.Server : ", v.Info.Chat.Server)
            if v.Info.Chat.Server == "g.us" {
                groupInfo, err := client.GetGroupInfo(v.Info.Chat)
                fmt.Println("error GetGroupInfo : ", err)
                fmt.Println("Nama Group : ", groupInfo.GroupName.Name)
            }
            if v.Info.MediaType == "livelocation" {
                lloc := v.Message.LiveLocationMessage
                fmt.Printf("liveloc %T\n", lloc)
                fmt.Println("Latitude : ", lloc.DegreesLatitude)
                fmt.Println("Longitude : ", lloc.DegreesLongitude)
                fmt.Println("livelocation : ", lloc)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    dbLog := waLog.Stdout("Database", "DEBUG", true)
    // Make sure you add appropriate DB connector imports, e.g. github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 for SQLite
    container, err := sqlstore.New("sqlite3", "file:gowa.db?_foreign_keys=on", dbLog)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // If you want multiple sessions, remember their JIDs and use .GetDevice(jid) or .GetAllDevices() instead.
    deviceStore, err := container.GetFirstDevice()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    clientLog := waLog.Stdout("Client", "DEBUG", true)
    client = whatsmeow.NewClient(deviceStore, clientLog)
    client.AddEventHandler(eventHandler)

    if client.Store.ID == nil {
        // No ID stored, new login
        qrChan, _ := client.GetQRChannel(context.Background())
        err = client.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        for evt := range qrChan {
            if evt.Event == "code" {
                // Render the QR code here
                // e.g. qrterminal.GenerateHalfBlock(evt.Code, qrterminal.L, os.Stdout)
                // or just manually `echo 2@... | qrencode -t ansiutf8` in a terminal
                fmt.Println("QR code:", evt.Code)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Login event:", evt.Event)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Already logged in, just connect
        err = client.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    // Listen to Ctrl+C (you can also do something else that prevents the program from exiting)
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-c

    client.Disconnect()
}
```